# What packages my project uses in a conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a project and I am looking to create an isolated python distribution that ONLY contains the packages/modules required by my project.

I have been developing in an anaconda environment.

If I do `conda list --export > requirements.txt`, this gives all the packages my environment uses.

I don't want my project to install every one of these packages on another machine as it only needs a handful I'm sure.

Is there a way to only list the packages my project requires (in conda).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs), it generates your requirements from the imports of your project.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach is to test your project in a virtual environment:

1. [create](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) an virtual environment
2. run your project and install the required dependencies, e.g. `> conda install <dependency>`
3. save dependencies to `requirements.txt` via the OP command

This will create an isolated `requirements.txt`.

See also [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [`poetry`](https://poetry.eustace.io/).  These tools create virtual environments of your project automatically and track your dependencies reliably.